# GCMInternet service.java mBuilder setColor error in java

Tags: java

this line-> `mBuilder.setColor(iconColor);`

showing error as method `setColor(int)` is undefined for the type `NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder`

here is my code

```
private void setNotificationIconColor(String color, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, String localIconColor)
{
    int iconColor = 0;
    if (color != null) {`enter code here`
        try {
            iconColor = Color.parseColor(color);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "couldn't parse color from android options");
        }
    }
    else if (localIconColor != null) {
        try {
            iconColor = Color.parseColor(localIconColor);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "couldn't parse color from android options");
        }
    }
    if (iconColor != 0) {
        mBuilder.setColor(iconColor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it for push notification as Phonegap/Cordova project just do below steps update code before Emulate:

```
private void setNotificationIconColor(String color, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, String localIconColor)
{
    int iconColor = 0;
    if (color != null) {`enter code here`
        try {
            iconColor = Color.parseColor(color);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "couldn't parse color from android options");
        }
    }
    else if (localIconColor != null) {
        try {
            iconColor = Color.parseColor(localIconColor);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "couldn't parse color from android options");
        }
    }
    if (iconColor != 0) {
        //mBuilder.setColor(iconColor);
    }
}
```